# Is there a way to get my street address from the Facebook Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there a permission I can add to my application's auth token to get a my street address? I can see how to get "current city", but beyond that; short of scraping the HTML, I don't see how to get street address.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [fql](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=fql?q=SELECT%20current_location%20FROM%20user%20WHERE%20uid=me%28%29) to query for current_location. This woulld return someting like:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "current_location": {
        "resultType": {
          "fieldTypes": {
            "street": {
              "strict": false
            },
            "city": {
              "strict": false
            },
            "state": {
              "strict": false
            },
            "country": {
              "strict": false
            },
            "zip": {
              "strict": false
            },
            "latitude": {
              "min": null,
              "max": null,
              "strict": false
            },
            "longitude": {
              "min": null,
              "max": null,
              "strict": false
            },
            "id": {
              "min": null,
              "max": null,
              "strict": false
            },
            "name": {
              "strict": false
            }
          },
          "includeNullFields": false
        },
        "street": null,
        "city": "Beirut",
        "state": "Beyrouth",
        "country": "Lebanon",
        "zip": "",
        "latitude": null,
        "longitude": null,
        "id": 106188806084417,
        "name": "Beirut, Lebanon"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Did you mean something like that.
Hope it helps

Comment: This returns the current city, but does not include street.